# Looking for a linear equation (I think)

Tags: linear-algebra, programming

I'm learning computer programming and I am trying to solve a problem that I think may have an algebraic solution.

I am trying to create a sequence of numbers that starts with adding a number to itself and then taking the result and adding that to itself and so on until the sequence is created.

I need to achieve this with a single-lined expression because I cannot reassign varibles using multiple line of code due to school assignment constraints.

I need to take something like this:

```
y = x + x

x = y
```

and turn it into a single lined equation.

Can anybody guide me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say you are creating a sequence, are you needing to store the sequence in an array?  Or are you just printing each term to the console?  Which language are you using?

Comment: so... if you start with $7$ you'd do $7, 14, 28, 56, 112, etc$?  Notice you are doubling each term so is you start with $k$ after $m$ iterations you will have $k*2^{m}$.  Is that the type of answer you are looking for or do you have a difference question about the process of coding.

Comment: so... what exactly is the *goal* of the question?  Why are they *asking* you to do this?  Do the want you to be able to mathematically express without a loop what the results will be?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with this:

```
x=x+x
```

Comment: Some languages even allow for ```x += x```. But it also seems you are multiplying by 2 each time so you could solve that way as well.

Comment: indeed you're right! Nice remark! Yeah `x*=2` can do as you said.